# How to interpret/plot a Poisson regression with quadratic effects moderated by one variable?

Tags: interaction, poisson-regression

I was originally trying to find evidence for a simple interaction effect in a Poisson regression model. However, after reading this paper by [Dawson (2014)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10869-013-9308-7) I realized that I might be in the presence of quadratic effects moderated by one variable. When I tested for a curvilinear relationship between Y and X11, moderated by Z, I indeed found full statistical support. I'm, however, unable to interpret this complex model. Dawson provides some Excel templates to plot simpler interaction relationships in Poisson models in his [website](http://www.jeremydawson.com/slopes.htm). He does not, however, offers a similar tool for plotting this type of model. I'm looking for some help in 1) trying to understand how the curvilinear moderation works in my model, and 2) hopefully instructions on how to plot it either in R or manually in excel.

My full model results (unstandardized coefficients, I can provide the standardized version if needed):

```
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         5.440595   2.316878   2.348 0.018862 *  
X1                 -0.405122   0.103848  -3.901 9.57e-05 ***
X2                  0.019043   0.005579   3.413 0.000643 ***
X3                  0.436697   1.747909   0.250 0.802711    
X4                  5.987939   1.729220   3.463 0.000535 ***
X5                  0.217285   0.079429   2.736 0.006227 ** 
X6                  0.931712   0.514717   1.810 0.070273 .  
X7                 -0.471429   0.220306  -2.140 0.032364 *  
X8                  0.020552   0.468405   0.044 0.965003    
X9                  0.366096   0.202013   1.812 0.069949 .  
X10                -0.051511   0.019788  -2.603 0.009236 ** 
Dummy2              1.240192   0.388951   3.189 0.001430 ** 
Dummy3              2.184451   0.446424   4.893 9.92e-07 ***
Dummy4             -0.704475   0.474565  -1.484 0.137685    
Dummy5              0.872217   0.397768   2.193 0.028323 *  
Dummy6              0.392920   0.392290   1.002 0.316535    
Dummy7              1.480901   0.441860   3.352 0.000804 ***
Dummy8              2.134915   0.389127   5.486 4.10e-08 ***
X11                -7.875909   2.427625  -3.244 0.001177 ** 
X11sq               1.274736   0.572026   2.228 0.025850 *  
Z                  -5.376412   1.229770  -4.372 1.23e-05 ***
X11:Z               4.890280   1.175421   4.160 3.18e-05 ***
X11sq:Z            -0.805803   0.259859  -3.101 0.001929 **
```

Comment: You haven't said what your link function is. Do you want the relationship on the scale of the linear predictot or on the scale of the response? Are you only interested in plotting the relationship of Y with X11 and Z? Without some information about the dummies and the other X variables it's hard to suggest whether the other covariates should be at their means, or whether the dummies should be at 0, 1 or at their own means (the choice matters more on the response scale than on the scale of the linear predictor)

Comment: I'm running a standard GLM Poisson regression in r, so a log link function. Ideally I'd like the relationship to be on the scale of the dependent variable (the counts). I'd only be interested in plotting the curvilinear relationship between Y and X11 with low and high values of Z. The other X variables are controls like company size, research and development, etc. And the dummies all refer to the industris (9 industries, 8 dummies). Hopefully this info would be sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the other covariates are fine at their means. Less sure about the industry dummies, but probably all zero? ( so at the base dummy?)

Comment: 1. At the base dummy could be reasonable; an alternative might be to take a weighted average of all the industries' coefficients (not forgetting the baseline) or even the modal industry (possibly adding in lighter curves for the highest and lowest industry coefficients).  2. I take it from your description just then that $Z$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, Z continuous. All options for the industry dummies look very interesting. If possible I'd like to explore the 3 options.